# Javascript - getOwnPropertyDescriptor & defineProperty on DOM prototype elements

Tags: javascript, dom, properties, ecmascript-5

I am trying to capture read/write operations on any IMG tag's "src" attribute. For that purpose I was trying to use the getOwnPropertyDescriptor & defineProperty functions on the HTMLImageElement object (since I'd like to avoid defining them for each img)
What I saw regarding getOwnPropertyDescriptor:

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(HTMLImageElement);
var own = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, "src");
// own is undefined in IE10/FF8/Chrome15
```

Regarding defineProperty on the proto element above, I saw that the getter/setter functions only run in Chrome, but not when I would expect them to and that "this" inside the getter function is the prototype of the DOM window. My test code for this can be found at  http://jsfiddle.net/yoav/tUekJ/

Should getOwnPropertyDescriptor work in this case? Should I expect the getter/setter functions to be triggered when JS accesses the "src" attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src`is a instance property, not a prototype property. Use something like the [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548686.aspx#sectionToggle3):

```
    var own = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLImageElement.prototype, "setAttribute");
```

**References**

- [Approach of new Object methods in ES5](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-April/010917.html)